# 'row names containing missing values' error when using HSD.test

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm trying to obtain means identified by different letters when they are significantly different.

When I use `HSD.test`I get the following error:

```
> aov1 <- aov(S ~ TAMBO, data=base)
> summary(aov1)
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
 TAMBO           5    216   43.26   9.197 9.44e-09 ***
 Residuals   14091  66281    4.70                     
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 14 observations deleted due to missingness
> hsdst <- HSD.test(aov1,"TAMBO", console=TRUE)

 Study: aov1 ~ "TAMBO"

 HSD Test for S 

 Mean Square Error:  4.703751 

 TAMBO,  means

 Error in data.frame(row.names = means[, 1], means[, -1]) : 
 row names contain missing values
```

I have tried `make.names(base, unique=TRUE)`and `rownames(base) <- NULL`but nothing seems to work. Also, when I used `TukeyHSD(aov1)`it worked fine. I've been the last ten hours with this, it's driving me crazy.

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have also used `lm`instead of `aov`. It made no difference.

EDIT 2: Here is `dput(head(base))`:

```
structure(list(TAMBO = structure(c(6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"AGR", "ER", "LE", "SN", "TLH"), class = "factor"), RP = structure(c(1013L, 
1136L, 228L, 1296L, 1237L, 1492L), .Label = c("", "  5 G", " E831", 
"1", "10", "100", "100-0002-01 - LA JOSEFA           ", "100-0007-01 - EL      REJUNTE          ", 
"100-0019-01 - FAC.CIENCIAS AGRP. ", "100-0036-01 - LA EFIGENIA         ", 
"1000", "1003", "1004", "1010", "1015", "1018", "102", "1020", 
"1021", "1027", "1031", "104", "106", "107", "108", "1083", "1084", 
"1088", "109", "1097", "11", "110", "1100", "1106", "111", "112", 
"1127", "114", "1149", "115", "1150", "116", "1161", "1162", 
"117", "118", "119", "1197", "12", "120", "1202", "1209", "121", 
"1210", "1212", "1215", "1219", "122", "1229", "123", "124", 
"1240", "125", "1250", "1254", "1258", "126", "1260", "127", 
"1275", "128", "1284", "1287", "129", "1295", "1298", "1299", 
"13", "130", "1300", "1302", "1304", "131", "132", "1326", "133", 
"1330",  "881", "882", "883", "884", 
"885", "886", "89", "890", "892", "893", "894", "895", "896", 
"899", "9", "90", "900", "91", "92", "93", "94", "944", "96", 
"960", "97", "971", "979", "9794", "98", "980", "988", "99", 
"9929"), class = "factor"), FECHA.NAC = structure(c(36L, 774L, 
554L, 398L, 1051L, 1L), .Label = c("", "00/00/00 ", "1980-05-20", 
"1980-06-05", "1980-11-15", "1981-06-15", "1983-08-12", "1983-08-20",       "2006-04-01", "2006-04-20", 
"2006-04-25", "2006-05-03", "2006-05-10", "2006-05-20", "2006-06-09", 
"2006-06-14", "2006-07-10", "2006-08-06", "2006-11-04", "2006-12-03", 
"2006-12-15", "2007-02-17", "2007-03-01", "2007-07-05", "31/11/02 "
), class = "factor"), NP = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L), NP.AGRUPADO = c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L), PARTO = structure(c(412L, 1962L, 1688L, 
2859L, 3106L, 3106L), .Label = c("1990-10-02", "1990-12-02", 
"1991-01-22", "1991-04-30", "1991-05-08", "1991-05-09", "1991-05-24", 
"1991-06-02", "1991-06-04", "1991-06-17", "1991-06-18", "1991-07-04", 
"1991-07-12", "1991-07-21", "1991-08-07", "1991-08-13", "1991-08-16", 
"1991-08-17", "1991-08-22", "1991-08-23", "1991-08-24", "1991-08-27", 
"1991-08-29", "1991-09-06", "1991-09-07", "1991-09-16", "1991-09-26", 
"2013-03-26", "2013-03-28", "2013-04-01", "2013-04-02", "2013-04-03", 
"2013-04-04", "2013-04-05", "2013-04-06", "2013-04-07", "2013-04-08", 
"2013-04-09", "2013-04-11", "2013-04-13", "2013-04-15", "2013-04-16", 
"2013-04-17", "2013-04-18", "2013-04-19", "2013-04-20", "2013-04-22", 
"2013-04-23", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-27", "2013-04-28", 
"2013-04-29", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-01", "2013-05-02", "2013-05-04", 
"2013-05-05", "2013-05-06", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-09", "2013-05-10", 
"2013-05-11", "2013-05-12", "2013-05-13", "2013-05-14", "2013-05-15", 
"2013-05-16", "2013-05-17", "2013-05-18", "2013-05-19", "2013-05-20", 
"2013-05-21", "2013-05-22", "2013-05-23", "2013-05-24", "2013-05-26", 
"2013-05-27", "2013-05-28", "2013-05-29", "2013-05-30", "2013-05-31", 
"2013-06-01", "2013-06-02", "2013-06-03", "2013-06-04", "2013-06-05", 
"2013-06-06", "2013-06-07", "2013-06-08", "2013-06-09", "2013-06-10", 
"2013-06-11", "2013-06-12", "2013-06-13", "2013-06-14", "2013-06-16", 
"2013-06-18", "2013-06-19", "2013-06-20", "2013-06-21", "2013-06-22", 
"2013-06-23", "2013-06-25", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-27", "2013-06-28"
), class = "factor"), ano = c(1994L, 2001L, 2000L, 2004L, 2004L, 
2004L), EDAD.1.PARTO = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), SEXO.CRIA = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", "--", " -H", " -M", " H", 
" M", "H", "HH", "HM", "M", "MH", "MM", "XX"), class = "factor"), 
TIPO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
" -N", " N", "IN", "N", "PA", "PR", "XX"), class = "factor"), 
ESTADO = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"-", "M", "V", "X"), class = "factor"), IPPC = c(15L, 15L, 
39L, 0L, 35L, 35L), IPPS = c(67L, 68L, 87L, 0L, 35L, 35L), 
S = c(3L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 7L, 7L), IPC = c(110L, 127L, 127L, 
0L, 425L, 325L), LECHE = c(21587L, 5937L, 10483L, 5576L, 
7684L, 7684L), DIAS. = c(0L, 8L, 22L, 19L, 29L, 29L), lecheaj = c(NA, 
226348L, 145333L, 89509L, 80814L, 80814L), X = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 254L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"1992-12-31", "1993-01-11", "1993-01-12", "1993-04-23", "1993-12-02", 
"1994-02-11", "1994-02-12", "1994-04-27", "1994-05-15", "1994-10-18", 
"1994-11-15", "1994-12-20", "1995-05-07", "1995-05-10", "1995-06-10", 
"1995-06-19", "1995-08-07", "1995-08-15", "1995-09-30", "1995-10-06", 
"2006-11-08", "2006-11-09", "2006-12-07", "2006-12-15", "2006-12-20", 
"2007-01-02", "2007-01-05", "2007-02-15", "2007-02-28", "2007-03-12", 
"aborto"), class = "factor"), xx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
9L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", " \\DA\\ ", " \\DE\\ ", " \\DP\\ ", 
" \\DX\\ ", " \\MA\\ ", " \\MI\\ ", " \\ML\\ ", " \\MO\\ ", 
" \\MP\\ ", " \\MS\\ ", " \\MT\\ ", " \\MX\\ "), class = "factor"), 
nivelprod = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ALTA", 
"BAJA", "MEDIA"), class = "factor"), PM = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("multi", "primi"), class = "factor"), 
EST = structure(c(3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("invierno", 
"otono", "primavera", "verano"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("TAMBO", 
"RP", "FECHA.NAC", "NP", "NP.AGRUPADO", "PARTO", "ano", "EDAD.1.PARTO", 
"SEXO.CRIA", "TIPO", "ESTADO", "IPPC", "IPPS", "S", "IPC", "LECHE", 
"DIAS.", "lecheaj", "X", "x", "xx", "nivelprod", "PM", "EST"), row.names =    c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What data are you using? Can you add an example of it to your question? Or can you reproduce this problem using a built in dataset like `mtcars` or `iris`?

Comment: also since HSD.test is not base R, which package do you use? Is it agricolae ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers!! I used agricolae, and could not reproduce the issue with mtcars. I added the results of `head(base)` to the question to show a sample of my data.

Comment: would you mind adjusting the `head(base)` to be `dput(head(base))`?

Comment: Done. I had to delete data due to the character limit, but it was similar to the data showed. I hope it helps, I have no clue what is dput used for :/

Comment: Ok, so I'm pretty desperate right now. Is there at least another way to identify which means are significantly different and which not? Tukey shows which comparison are significant, but I need to be able to report which means are different and which are not. Thanks!!!

Comment: I had the same error, then I realized one of my factors was a blank. After I removed it HSD.test worked .